# Did Robert Jordan comment on ra'angreal in the Wheel of Time series?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Near the end of "Eye of the World" in Chapter 52, when Moraine is explaining to the others what cuendillar is, she uses the term *ra'angreal*:

> "Cuendillar, " Moiraine said. "Heartstone. No one has been able to
>   make it since the Age of Legends, and even then it was made only for
>   the greatest purpose. Once made, nothing can break it. Not the One
>   Power itself wielded by the greatest Aes Sedai who ever lived aided by
>   the most powerful ra'angreal ever made. Any power directed against
>   heartstone only makes it stronger."

Later books establish that there are are three types of objects which can enhance one's ability to use the One Power:

- *ter'angreal*; an object imbued with the Power to serve a specific purpose
- *angreal*; an object designed to strengthen one's ability to use the Power
- *sa'angreal*; the most powerful, which can massively increase ability to channel

As far as I could tell, the term *ra'angreal* is never used again in the series. Either it's a case of the author not yet establishing the terminology (it IS the first book after all), or it's a typo in the physical copy I own (a hardback reprint).

**Did Robert Jordan ever comment on this discrepancy, or is it simply a typo that was meant to say sa'angreal?**

Comment: Maybe it’s inclusive of the three categories you mentioned?

Comment: If so, I think that's the only time he uses it. AFAIK, the overall term used for all three throughout the series is "angreal".

Comment: I would swear my physical copy says *sa'angreal*.  My ebook copy *definitely* has *sa'angreal*.This has every feel of a typo.

Comment: @Radhil - that's the way I'm leaning, too, but wanted to be sure. I'm not sure what edition I have, but if other books out there have "sa'angreal", then it's a confirmed typo in that one edition

Comment: I can confirm they say sa'angreal in the audio book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my physical copy (Tor, US paperback):

[image]

So yes, *ra'angreal* seems to be a typo of *sa'angreal*.